# How should this querystring value be formatted in ajax input

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am modifying a code example that I will use (and not very familiar with Javascript)

This is the piece of code

```
function chk() { cnt++;
 var resp=ajax('chk.php', 'POST', 'ordernr='XXXXXX'&r='+((new Date()).getTime()));
 if (resp=='3') {
```

I am posting to this file withe a Querystring-varaible named ordenr

What is the correct syntax to enter the value of Querystring.ordernr instead of XXXXXX

Comment: `'ordernr=' + encodeURIComponent(yourJavaScriptVariableName) + '&` etc

Comment: If I understand your question correctly this should answer it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: And probably this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var orderNumber = 1;

var requestParamsStr = 'ordernr=\'' + orderNumber + '\'&r=' + ((new Date()).getTime());

console.log(requestParamsStr);

function chk() {
  //cnt++;
  var resp = ajax('chk.php', 'POST', encodeURIComponent(requestParamsStr));
  //rest of code
}
```

I think I understand your question. If you need to put quotes around the order number then you must use the escape character `/` the way I'm doing in the code snippet, so that it doesn't delimit the string (or, alternatively, you could use double quotes within the single quotes). You must also use `+` to concatenate the the strings.

**UPDATE**:
I've encoded the request param string as per @ADyson's comment.

Comment: the parameters could do with url-encoding as well, to avoid problems with special characters etc. We don't know for sure what the content of orderNr will actually be - might not really be a number. Anyway it's just good practice in general.